# How to install libboost_version1.59 or newer on Ubuntu16.04

Tags: compiling, c++, libraries

How can I install libboost1.59 ?

I have tried many methods to install it, but fail to update the version 1.58 on my Ubuntu 16.04 to the version 1.59.

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12578499/how-to-install-boost-on-ubuntu) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38426692/installing-boost-1-59-0-ubuntu) on StackOverflow, [this on linuxfromscratch.org](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/7.8/general/boost.html) and [this blog post](http://juniway.blogspot.sg/2015/12/install-boost-1590-build-from-source.html)

Who can give me an effective method?

Comment: Did you try the get the __boost version__ you want example ?

Comment: I take it that upgrading to 16.10 is not an option?

Answer (score 6):

To get the latest go to [boost on SourceForge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost/), then:

1. Download and extract with `tar -xf boost_X_XX_X.tar.gz` where XX is the version number, like `tar -xf boost_1_62_0.tar.gz`.
2. `cd boost_X_XX_X`
3. Get required libraries:

   ```
    sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install build-essential g++ python-dev autotools-dev libicu-dev libbz2-dev libboost-all-dev
   ```
4. Build with: `./bootstrap.sh --prefix=/usr/local`
5. Install with: `sudo ./b2 install`

Please note you can also get the version currently on your version of Ubuntu can be gotten at [the `libboost-dev` package page on UbuntuUpdates](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/xenial/main/base/libboost-dev).

Comment: Thanks， I tried this method, it will install the version1.58 in required libraries libboost-all-dev, The libboost 1.58 comes with Ubuntu 16.04 system, so I re-build a ubuntu 16.10 version. Thanks for you help

Comment: It seems that `sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev` still installs the most recent version of boost for the current Ubuntu version (boost 1.54 for Ubuntu 14.04), while the whole purpose of the above instruction is to install a newer version... How do I overcome this?

Comment: Great answer! Worked for me.